# how to keep state in vue jsx component?

Tags: jsx, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i want to render a search input in table column heads, it needs keeping a `keyword` state in itself, but it's value won't change with user input. so how to resolve the `keyword` state?

[image]
text code here

```
function renderInputFilter(submit: (keyword: string) => void) {
  const keyword = ref('')
  return <div>
    <ElInput placeholder="input keyword" v-model={keyword.value} />
    <ElButton type="primary" icon="el-icon-search" onClick={() => submit(keyword.value)} />
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this part:
`v-model={keyword.value}`
Change it to
`v-model={keyword}`

[You don't need to use .value in the template because refs are automatically "unwrapped" in the template.](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping):

> When a ref is returned as a property on the render context (the object returned from setup()) and accessed in the template, it automatically shallow unwraps the inner value. Only the nested ref will require .value in the template: